# Remove Numbering (and "()") on SubFloats (in a table)

Tags: tables, numbering, subfloats

So I have set of three tabular environments in a table:

```
\begin{table}[h]

\centering
\scriptsize

\subfloat[``student" data table]{
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \toprule
Column Name &  Data Type \\\midrule
id* & Integer \\
name & Text  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\qquad\qquad
\subfloat[``term\_gpa" data table]{
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \toprule
Column Name &  Data Type \\\midrule
id* & Integer \\
term* & Integer \\
gpa & Float \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\qquad\qquad
\subfloat[``degrees" data table]{
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \toprule
Column Name &  Data Type \\\midrule
id* & Integer \\
term & Integer \\
degree* & Char(5) \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\end{table}
```

[image: Table Environment]

Everything looks great, however the "(a)", "(b)", "(c)", has confused some users as being the names of the tables.  I'm trying to remove those, however, when I add this:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\relax}
```

I get each being labeled "()"; so it is suppressing the numbering, but still includes the parathesis.

Any ideas.  I'm hoping it is something simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please make your code fully compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}`, including the relevant packages, and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `subfig` uses the `caption` package, you can use

```
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=empty}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

\centering
\scriptsize
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=top,labelformat=empty}
\subfloat[``student" data table]{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lcc} \toprule
Column Name &  Data Type \\\midrule
id* & Integer \\
name & Text  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\qquad\qquad
\subfloat[``term\_gpa" data table]{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lcc} \toprule
Column Name &  Data Type \\\midrule
id* & Integer \\
term* & Integer \\
gpa & Float \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\qquad\qquad
\subfloat[``degrees" data table]{
\begin{tabular}[t]{lcc} \toprule
Column Name &  Data Type \\\midrule
id* & Integer \\
term & Integer \\
degree* & Char(5) \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, using `[h]` as placement specifier might be too restrictive; you could try using something like `[ht]` or `[hb]`.