# Set numbering of subcaption off with beamer and subfloat in subfig package

Tags: beamer, subfloats

I am using `beamer` and the `subfig` package. I use the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[Graph1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Graph1}}
\subfloat[Graph2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Graph1}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, my figure has the following "()" for the place which would have (a), (b), etc in its subcaptions. How do I prevent "()" from appearing in the subcaptions? Note that I would like to have captions, just don't need the additional ().

If this is impossible to figure out, at least the counter for the subcpation

It does work with using `subfigure` and not `subfloat` and the `subfigure` package but I am trying to get out of `subfigure`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), not only pieces of code.

Comment: done, thanks. Was not sure about how to put in figures.

Comment: Add`\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=empty}`to your preamble, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106849/124842. -  Hint: For example images in questions you can use \subfloat[Graph1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `labelformat=empty` to your preamble like this:

`\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=empty}`

->Result: Subcaptions `Graph1` and `Graph2` without "()":
[image]

Full working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


\title{}
\author{}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Graph1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}}
\subfloat[Graph2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```